# How to use lists as input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to take array as input and print it like this(i think 2d array format) what kind of codes  should i use?
I tried normal input() function but i couldn't convert it to an array.

**Input:**`[[’a’, ’b’, ’c’, ’d’, ’e’],  [’f’, ’g’, ’h’, ’i’, ’j’],  [’k’, ’l’, ’m’, ’n’, ’o’],  [’p’, ’q’, ’r’, ’s’, ’t’],  [’u’, ’v’, ’w’, ’x’, ’y’]]`

**Output:**

`a b c d e`

`f g h i j`

`k l m n o`

`p q r s t`

`u v w x y`

Comment: convert it into string and use replace method

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Congratulations on your first post. What have you tried? Add your code and any errors/output to your question and that will help others find solutions to your problem. It may be helpful to you to read: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Praveen then how should i print them each in a row

Comment: use a loop which prints in the next line after every 5 letters

Answer (score 0):

```
row = int(input("Enter no. of Rows : "))

array = []

for x in range(row):
    line = input("Enter Row no. %d (Space Separeted):"%(x+1))
    array.append(line.split())

# To Show The Array
for x in array:
    for y in x:
        print(y , end = " ")
    print()
```

Or You Can Use

```
array = eval(input())
```

But in this case you have to enter the input enclosing `[]` and comma separated ,as the list appears.

Answer (score 0):

If you trust the input simply:

```
array = eval(input.replace("’", "\'"))
```

the rest is simple:

```
for l in array:
    for c in l:
        print(c,end=" ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = eval(input())
for arr in array:
    print(" ".join(arr))
```